# Reference formula values in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this sheet which is filled with loads of formulas and all of them make reference to a date range that I select from 3 different dropdowns.

My issue is, that the formulas are getting really long and because there are so many its hard to keep track of if they are all connected to the right dropdowns.

The formulas look something like this

```
=COUNTIFS(MachineData!Z:Z,"Patient",MachineData!$N:$N,"*london*",MachineData!$X:$X,"N",MachineData!$C:$C,">="&(DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19)-30),MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19)+1)
```

My question is, is there any way that I can put this part of the formula

```
MachineData!$C:$C,">="&(DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19)-30),MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19)+1)
```

into a cell and then instead of having to type it into every formula then I can be like MachineData!C:C,D4 or something like that. I dont know if this is possible.

Comment: No this is not possible, but other work arounds may be possible.  If you would show us what you have (visually) and what exactly you want to do, we may be able to help simplify the formulas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things I would consider.  First you could simplify part of the formula by wrapping the COUNTIFS function with the LET function.

So your formula would look something like this:

```
=LET(myDates,DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19),COUNTIFS(MachineData!Z:Z,"Patient",MachineData!$N:$N,"*london*",MachineData!$X:$X,"N",MachineData!$C:$C,">="&(myDates-30),MachineData!$C:$C,"<="&myDates+1))
```

That doesn't help much. But it is better.

To accomplish something closer to what you want, try the INDIRECT function.

Say you put "MachineData!$C:$C" into cell A1. You could then use INDIRECT(A1) wherever you want to use that reference. Or you could use it in conjunction with LET and it might look something like this:

```
=LET(myDates,DATE($R$23,$R$21,$R$19),myRange,INDIRECT(A1),
COUNTIFS(MachineData!Z:Z,"Patient",MachineData!$N:$N,"*london*",MachineData!$X:$X,"N",myRange,">="&(myDates-30),myRange,"<="&myDates+1)
)
```

Follow the links for more on the [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) or [INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) functions.

Note that LET is only available to Microsoft 365 subscribers.

Finally, did you consider named ranges?

Answer (score 0):

When formulas start to get too long and complicated, you might want to consider replacing them with user defined functions. You can do anything in a UDF that you can do in a formula and they are a lot easier to maintain and extend.

For example, you could create the following UDF in the worksheet module.

```
Function MyUDF1()

    Dim year As Integer
    Dim month As Integer
    Dim day As Integer
    Dim dt As Date
  
    year = Me.Cells(23, 18).Value     '$R$23
    month = Me.Cells(21, 18).Value    '$R$21
    day = Me.Cells(19, 18).Value      '$R$19
    dt = DateSerial(year, month, day)
    
    MyUDF1= WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( _
        Me.Columns(26), "Patient", _
        Me.Columns(14), "*london*", _
        Me.Columns(24), "N", _
        Me.Columns(3), ">=" & (dt - 30), _
        Me.Columns(3), "<=" & dt) + 1
    
End Function
```

And then the formula in the cell becomes simply "=MyUDF1()"